# Adding a power button to laptop for using as SBC

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power, button-remapping, soc

My laptop power button is included with the keyboard. And when I remove the keyboard from the keyboard port of motherboard, there is no way to start the laptop.

The reason I want to remove keyboard is:

1. The laptop has an SoC Atom processor and consumes very low power.
2. I would like to take the SoC like a raspberry Pi and connect it to power behind my monitor and use it as a full time torrent machine.

[motherboard with the keyboard ribbon cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP6fv.jpg)

This is the image of the keyboard ribbon cable.

Is there a way to add a power button on to this SoC and use it as a windows 10 RPi without the keyboard.

The one way to turn on the SoC is to short the 3rd pin to ground as shown in many YouTube videos but it won’t be accessible once I hide it behind the monitor.

I have already checked BIOS. There is no way to turn on pc with AC power on.

Thank you for reading my request.

Comment: Solder a wire to the pin and a button to your wire and to ground. If you no longer need the keyboard at all, you could remove the entire connector too.

Comment: @towe That could work. Really, that could work but soldering a wire to the 3rd pin without touching the other pins is a task I am not having confidence. But thank you for this idea. If nothing else work, I will use this. I don’t know to reply to your conment and so I added an @.

Comment: Alternatively, again if you don't need the keyboard, you might be able to cut the keyboard PCB in order to only retain the ribbon cable connector, and solder the cable to that end.
I don't think it'll get much easier than that on a hardware level. Perhaps there's a BIOS update available for e.g. Wake-on-LAN?

Comment: @towe Again thanks for further input. I never checked the update to bios. If I am able to get wake on AC, that would be perfect. I will surely check that. I would not damage the ribbon cable or the port where the ribbon goes to because in future, if I change my mind then it would be really hard to get the components, set aside the solder job. When I solder, there will be huge chunks of lead in contact. Again thank you for the bios update advise.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter and lots of free time? You could try to trace 'which' traces on the keyboard are active when the power button is pressed and work from there.

Comment: Some good guy in YouTube has already found it out for me. But thanks for the info. For an new product I could do it myself. I don’t have a MM but I am planning to get it soon.

Comment: @towe Can you please type the soldering a wire on the answer. I will accept the answer and close this question. That is a perfect solution. And an easy one. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solder a wire to the pin you've identified as the power button, and connect a momentary switch between that wire and ground.

Don't forget strain reliefs for the wire, as the solder connection might be susceptible to vibrations.